# Invalid column audio._id AS _id Android 11

Tags: android, api, android-11

hi as google decides to update all apps to targets api30 a Music player im working on Stopped Working on Android 11
with the logcat error

'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column audio._id AS _id'

```
   private Cursor openCursorAndGoToFirst(Uri uri, String[] projection,
                                          String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection,
                selection, selectionArgs, null);
        if (c == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (!c.moveToFirst()) {
            c.close();
            return null;
        }
        return c;
    }
```

```
private int getmCardId() {
        final ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = resolver.query(Uri.parse("content://media/external/fs_id"), null, null,
                null, null);
        int mCardId = -1;
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            mCardId = cursor.getInt(0);
            cursor.close();
            cursor = null;
        }
        return mCardId;
    }
```

any solution ?

Comment: Can you please add code where it's crashing? Post that Function or file.

Comment: Can you please update the code how you're calling the function `openCursorAndGoToFirst` ? I would like to know what are the values of `uri`, `projection`, `selection` , `selectionArgs`  ?